# Why a store value should not be updated directly?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

What happens if I update redux store values directly instead of dispatching an action?

Here an example code:

```
import actions from '../actions'

class Example extends Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.any,
    }

    static propTypes = {
        drawer: PropTypes.object,
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        const { drawer } = this.props 
        const { store } = this.context

        // I can update 'drawer' values directly and "it works" as following
        // drawer.unread -= 1

        // Also I can update 'drawer' values by dispatching an action as following
        drawer.unread -= 1
        this.context.store.dispatch(actions.updateDrawer(drawer))
    }

}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        drawer: state.drawer,
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Example)
```

Comment: Because if there are other components you want to re-render on `uiObjectProp` change - they won't unless you use dispatch. the state won't really change.

Comment: I thought so, but they change. I wonder if the situation I encountered is an exceptional or not. I'll update my question.

Comment: @efkan , interesting. Tried the same with a deeply nested object which was part of the store in my app and nothing happened and as per docs "The only way to change the state inside it is to dispatch an action on it" . I will fiddle around !

Comment: I changed the question as I've experienced. In my case, code of `this.props.drawer.unread -= 1` is enough to change the Drawer component values.

Comment: @efkan , created a simple ADD/SUB app. you can find it here https://codesandbox.io/s/zkkx3q21zx , if i try to subtract the prop received via store directly i am getting a "Cannot assign to read only property 'count' of object '#<Object>'"  !  You can fork the sandbox and try to replicate the issue , will help ! :)

Comment: https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html

Answer (score 0):

The state will change, but no component will be notified of the change.

Also, some optimizations (like  `React.PureComponent`) assume they can detect changes on the state using shallow reference equality. Directly assigning will break their assumption.

Comment: However my drawer component changes. Also I never try to update more deep nested objects. Maybe it works only on first level objects (like drawer: { unread: 3 })